# Add multi text to existing pdf using itext

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I have existed pdf template

Now I want to add some text to this file, so I did that:

```
 PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(path + PdfCreator.TEMPORARY);
 PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(path + PdfCreator.DEST));
 PdfContentByte canvasBookingDate = stamper.getOverContent(1);
 //add text "Hellow"
 canvasBookingDate.setFontAndSize(base, 9.5f);   
 canvasBookingDate.moveText(72f, 788f);
 canvasBookingDate.showText("Hello");
 canvasBookingDate.moveText(72f, 762f);
 //add text "How are you"
 canvasBookingDate.setFontAndSize(base, 9.5f);   
 canvasBookingDate.showText("How are you");
 canvasBookingDate.setTextRenderingMode(PdfContentByte.TEXT_RENDER_MODE_FILL_STROKE);
```

The problem is that, only "Hello" was inserted to pdf file, "How are you" was not
Maybe I wrong something there?

I also using seperate `PdfContentByte` object to write each text but no luck

```
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(path + PdfCreator.DEST));
 PdfContentByte canvasBookingDate = stamper.getOverContent(1);
 //add text "Hellow"
 canvasBookingDate.setFontAndSize(base, 9.5f);   
 canvasBookingDate.moveText(72f, 788f);
 canvasBookingDate.showText("Hello");
 canvasBookingDate.moveText(72f, 762f);

 //add text "How are you"
 PdfContentByte canvasPlanName2 = stamper.getOverContent(1);
 canvasPlanName2.setFontAndSize(base, 9.5f);   
 canvasPlanName2.moveText(72f, 762f);
 canvasPlanName2.showText(entity.getPlanName());
 canvasPlanName2.setTextRenderingMode(PdfContentByte.TEXT_RENDER_MODE_FILL_STROKE);
```

Comment: https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-jump-start-tutorial/chapter-5-manipulating-existing-pdf-document this may be helpful

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is that, only "Hello" was inserted to pdf file, "How are you" was not

Your observation is inaccurate: "How are you" was inserted, merely far off-page! (Doing CtrlA CtrlC from adobe reader and pasting into some editor you would have seen that it is there somewhere.)

The cause is that you misunderstand how `moveText` works. Have a look at its JavaDoc documentation:

```
/**
 * Moves to the start of the next line, offset from the start of the current line.
 *
 * @param       x           x-coordinate of the new current point
 * @param       y           y-coordinate of the new current point
 */
public void moveText(final float x, final float y)
```

Thus, the coordinates are relative, not absolute!

So you should do

```
canvasBookingDate.beginText();
canvasBookingDate.setFontAndSize(base, 9.5f);   
canvasBookingDate.moveText(72f, 788f);
canvasBookingDate.showText("Hello");
canvasBookingDate.moveText(0f, -16f);
//add text "How are you"
canvasBookingDate.showText("How are you");
canvasBookingDate.endText();
```

Answer (score 0):

I found answer from Vishal Kawade link
Just using `beginText()` and `endText()` after each text need insert to pdf

Comment: Yes, `beginText ()` and `endText ()` are important, too, but they are not required around each single text piece.

Comment: that being said, is there a specific reason why you use the most low level API of iText? Doing so you need to know details of pdf internals you can otherwise ignore.